VSCode: changing the file path used by the interactive editor
When running / executing code in the Jupyter-like interactive editor, data files are not found because the Jupyter interpreter is looking at a different directory than in which the file is being executed. This works fine when running a standard python file (in the standard terminal).
How can I change the filepath to be the parent of the current file being run? Strangely, this had been working correctly in the past (~ 6 months ago) so something in my settings or in the extension has changed (current Jupyter extension: v2024.5.0)
I've attempted without success:

changing the Jupyter -> Notebook File Root path to ${workspaceFolder} and then to ${fileDirname} per How to set the running file path of jupyter in VScode?. Also tried setting a absolute path there to a directory.
adding launch.json settings to include "cwd": "${fileDirname}" as recommended here: How to run python interactive in current file's directory in Visual Studio Code?

Apart from manually setting the filepath using os.chdir() I've not found any way to do this systematically; hoping there is a more up to date solution not mentioned in those earlier postings.

standard python file in standard terminal will have the same problem if you run it in wrong folder. But you can use cd other/folder to change folder. In Jupyter should also work !cd other/folder. But in starndard file you can at least use os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) to get folder with file.

Hi, as you described, it can be done through the Python OS module using os.chdir(). I've requested the relevant features from the developers. We can wait for new features.

@Jeanneli: Thank you for requesting the fix with the developers

Hello, with this issue, here's another way maybe you can try it. Try going to the directory of the kernel you're using. Then create ipython_kernel_config.py files in the same directory. Try adding c = get_config() c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ["import sys", "sys.path.append('/yourpath')",]
This allows it to be executed automatically when the kernel is started. See if you can get the results you want.
